# Letters of a bi-rationalist

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, birational-geometry

V.V. Shokurov has written several papers over the course of about 10 years which are called "Letters of a bi-rationalist". Here are the ones that I could find:

- [Letters of a bi-rationalist. I. A projectivity criterion](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/cheltsov/shokurov/pdf/letter1.pdf)

  [On rational connectedness](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1026631926763) (this is letter number 2, as you can see from the first line in the text)

  [Letters of a bi-rationalist. IV. Geometry of log flips](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0206004)

  [Letters of a bi-rationalist V: Mld's and termination of log flips](http://www.mathnet.ru/eng/tm165)

  [Letters of a bi-rationalist. VII. Ordered termination](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/cheltsov/shokurov/pdf/letter7.pdf)

The question is: what happened to the letters number III and VI?

Comment: Full list of publications appears here:  http://www.mi.ras.ru/index.php?c=pubs&id=11520&showmode=sci&showall=show&l=1

Comment: @joro : There are only four papers on that webpage entitled "Letters of a bi-rationalist" (the four listed by YangMills) so this doesn't quite answer the question.

Comment: Perhaps the other two "letters" were actual letters that Shokurov sent to other people and did not publish. But I have no evidence to support/refute this.